# Using VBA to PDF only the populated print areas within a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am very new to VBA and trying to create a macro that will export a PDF of only the print areas that have been populated with values from another sheet in the workbook.

I have a sheet with 8 A4 forms marked out with 8 separate print areas. Depending on the project we are working on, the number of forms filled and needed to be PDF'd varies. **I would like a simple macro that can detect which forms are blank, and not include them in the PDF.**

I was wondering if it is possible by using VBA to detect if a cell is blank or has any value and if it does contain a value, include it in the PDF? On the first form, cell R5 is an example of a cell that if it has any value, needs to be in the PDF.

Currently I'm using this code to PDF and rename. It is cobbled together from about three different tutorials and i'm sure looks very unwieldy.

```
Sub GenerateSDS()

Sheets("SDS").Select

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim lOver As Long
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet

strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

strName = wsA.Range("A92").Value _
          & " _ " & "SDS" & " _ " & "BLANK"

strFile = strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

If bFileExists(strPathFile) Then
  lOver = MsgBox("Overwrite existing file?", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File Exists")
  If lOver <> vbYes Then

    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
      (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
          FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
          Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
    If myFile <> "False" Then
      strPathFile = myFile
    Else
      GoTo exitHandler
    End If
  End If
End If

wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strPathFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("Enter Data Here").Select

MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & strPathFile

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
'=============================
Function bFileExists(rsFullPath As String) As Boolean
  bFileExists = CBool(Len(Dir$(rsFullPath)) > 0)
End Function
'=============================
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you understand by "only the print areas that have been populated with values from another sheet"? A sheet can have only one print area, so I suppose that you have something else in your mind... Do you mean parts of the sheet containing data? If yes, nobody can help you without seeing your workbook. Theoretically, according to the specificity of each worksheet, you must copy each such an area on a template worksheet of another workbook and nicely arrange them according to your taste. And then export the template workbook. Do, at least, those sheets have the same appearance ALL THE TIME?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! By print "areas" I mean that the print area has been divided by page breaks into 8 separate A4 sections. Each A4 page is a "blank" testing form template, and they're all the same until some scheduled testing information is imported into a different sheet in the workbook. This sheet then fills the forms out with required tests, personalising the individual A4 pages. I only wish to export the A4 pages that have had data added once the tests have been assigned. Currently I produce for example 3 useful pages with data and then the PDF has 5 blank pages at the end.

Comment: If you can control the number of pages printed with From and To parameters on ExportAsFixedFormat method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat